# Using ValueConverter to position a Line relative to its parent ActualHeight and another ViewModel property

Tags: xaml, data-binding, mvvm, ivalueconverter, element-binding

I have a property in my ViewModel called `RelativeHeight`, which is a double ranging from 0 to 1.

In my View, I have an horizontal line whose width is the same of its container (via `Element Binding`), but I want it to have its vertical position relative to the size of the container.

For example, if `RelativeHeight` is `0.3`, and the container's `ActualHeight` is `200`, then `Line.X1` and `Line.X2` would be `60` each.

Following code is what I got, but don't know how to use (or even if I should use in the first place) some `IValueConverter` because usually I can't get properties from the view whan calling the `Convert` method...

```
<Line Stroke="Red" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="5"
      X1="0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Graphs}"
      Y1="{Binding RelativeHeight, Converter=MaybeSomeConversion}"
      Y2="{Binding RelativeHeight, Converter=MaybeSomeConversion}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it with `IMultiValueConverter`, like this (variable names in portuguese):

```
... (resource dictionary)

<views:ConversorNível x:Key="conversorNivel"/>

....

<Line x:Name="line" Stroke="Red" Opacity="0.6" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" StrokeThickness="2"
      X1="0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Gráficos}"
      Y2="{Binding Y1, ElementName=line}" >
    <Line.Y1>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conversorNivel}">
            <Binding Path="NívelSelecionado" />
            <Binding ElementName="Gráficos" Path="ActualHeight" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Line.Y1>
</Line>
```

and in codebehind:

```
public class ConversorNível : IMultiValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)values[0] * (double)values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```